# C# program not getting results from SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I've written a function in C# to retrieve results from a TSQL query.

```
public List<string> ExecuteRule(string rule)
{
    List<string> foundLCNs = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        SqlDataReader myReader = null;
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand
        (
            rule, 
            myConnection 
        ); 
        myConnection.Open();

        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while(myReader.Read())
        {
            foundLCNs.Add(myReader["labno"].ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Controller.PrintStackTrace (e);
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
    return foundLCNs;
}
```

I am finding that when I run some SQL queries, no results are returned and yet, when I copy the SQL and run it in Microsoft SQL Server management sudio, I get some results.

Perhaps the query could be taking too long, but I'm not getting any exceptions thrown.

When I step through the code with the debugger
I hit this line

> myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

executes quickly (it should take a couple of seconds to retrieve the data).

The while loop never executes the code inside, it just skips over as no data is returned.

**EDIT**

The SQL looks like this

```
WITH FilterPatches AS
(
    SELECT 
        OIL_SAMPLE.labno 
    FROM OIL_SAMPLE 
    INNER JOIN LU_OIL_TEST_TYPE ON OIL_SAMPLE.test_type_auto = LU_OIL_TEST_TYPE.test_type_auto 
    LEFT JOIN OIL_EQ_UNIT ON OIL_SAMPLE.equnit_auto = OIL_EQ_UNIT.equnit_auto 
    LEFT JOIN Equipment ON OIL_EQ_UNIT.equipmentid_auto = Equipment.equipmentid_auto 
    LEFT JOIN CRSF ON Equipment.crsf_auto = CRSF.crsf_auto 
    LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER ON CRSF.customer_auto = CUSTOMER.customer_auto 
    LEFT JOIN OIL_SAMPLE_READING_STORE AS DEP ON OIL_SAMPLE.labno = DEP.labno 
    LEFT JOIN OIL_SAMPLE_READING AS DEP2 ON OIL_SAMPLE.labno_auto = DEP2.labno_auto 
    WHERE CUSTOMER.custid IN 
    ( 
        '555555', '555'
    ) AND 
    ( 
        (
            DEP.element_auto IN 
            ( 
                 SELECT element_auto 
                 FROM LU_OIL_ELEMENT 
                 WHERE LU_OIL_ELEMENT.elementid = 'DEP' 
            ) 
            AND 
            DEP.reading NOT IN ('vw', 'ok') 
        ) 
        OR 
        ( 
            DEP2.element_auto IN 
            ( 
                SELECT element_auto 
                FROM LU_OIL_ELEMENT 
                WHERE LU_OIL_ELEMENT.elementid = 'DEP' 
            ) 
            AND 
            DEP2.reading NOT IN ('vw', 'ok') 
            AND OIL_SAMPLE.data_released_date IS NULL
        )
    ) 
    AND OIL_SAMPLE.labno NOT IN
    ( 
        SELECT labno 
        FROM OIL_SAMPLE_READING_STORE 
        WHERE element_auto IN 
        ( 
            SELECT element_auto 
            FROM LU_OIL_ELEMENT 
            WHERE LU_OIL_ELEMENT.elementid = 'FPATCH' 
        ) 
    ) 
    AND LU_OIL_TEST_TYPE.test_type_desc NOT IN 
    (
        'Diesel',
        'DieselStd',
        'DieselSml'
    )
),
ParticleCountElements AS
(
    SELECT element_auto 
    FROM LU_OIL_ELEMENT 
    WHERE LU_OIL_ELEMENT.elementid IN
    (
        'AB',
        'CD'
    ) 
)
(

    SELECT labno
    FROM FilterPatches

    EXCEPT

    (
        SELECT DISTINCT labno
        FROM OIL_SAMPLE_READING_STORE
        WHERE element_auto IN
        (
            SELECT element_auto
            FROM ParticleCountElements
        )
        AND labno IN 
        (
            SELECT labno
            FROM FilterPatches
        )
        AND reading_raw IS NOT NULL

        UNION

        SELECT labno
        FROM OIL_SAMPLE 
        LEFT JOIN OIL_SAMPLE_READING ON OIL_SAMPLE.labno_auto = OIL_SAMPLE_READING.labno_auto 
        WHERE OIL_SAMPLE.data_released_date IS NULL
        AND OIL_SAMPLE_READING.element_auto IN
        (
            SELECT element_auto
            FROM ParticleCountElements
        )
        AND labno IN 
        (
            SELECT labno
            FROM FilterPatches
        )

    )
)
```

I've tried running this in microsoft sql server management studio and it works fine.

**EDIT**

As Will Suggested I have tried changing the code to

```
List<string> foundLCNs = new List<string>();

using (var cnx = new SqlConnection (ConnectionString)) 
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand (rule, cnx)) 
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cnx.Open ();

        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows) 
            {
                while (dr.Read ()) 
                {
                    if (!dr.IsDBNull (0)) 
                    {
                        foundLCNs.Add (dr.GetString (0));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return foundLCNs;
```

> dr.HasRows
>   is false

I'm still getting the same behaviour though. It works for other queries, but not the one that I posted. However this query does work when run in SQL server.

Comment: Have you checked that the account which executes the code has rights to query the database?

Comment: try setting the CommandType to CommandType.Text

Comment: What your query looks like?

Comment: @DeanOC Good thinking to check this, but the C# function works fine with other SQL queries, so it has access rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how your code shall look alike.

```
public IList<string> ExecuteRule(string rule) {
    var found = new List<string>();

    using (var cnx = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(rule, cnx)) {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            
            // Make sure to add values to parameters whenever required by your query.
            // e.g. cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", value);

            cnx.Open();

            using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
                if (dr.HasRows)
                    while (dr.Read()) 
                        if (!dr.IsDBNull(0)) 
                            found.Add(dr.GetStringValue(0));                                        
        }   

    return found;         
}
```

1. Checking for `null` values is always wise in order to handle them gracefully.
2. Setting the `cmd.CommandType` will tell ADO.NET how it shall execute your command.
3. Providing appropriate parameters, if any, is mandatory (yet it doesn't prove to be your case, since it runs with no error).
4. Always use `using` blocks so that your resources are disposed when getting out of scope.

[**using Statement (C# Reference)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> *Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of `IDisposable` objects.*

[**IDisposable**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)

> *Provides a mechanism for releasing unmanaged resources.*

Since your program seems to run fine, I can't figure out something else wrong unless you tell otherwise.

---

**dr.HasRows == false**

Seeing your SQL query for the first time, it is no surprise to me that your query times out.

From MSDN:

[**IDbCommand.CommandTimeout Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

> *Gets or sets the wait time before terminating the attempt to execute a command and generating an error.*
>
> [**Remarks (SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> *A value of 0 indicates no limit (an attempt to execute a command will wait indefinitely).*

I see you tried to set the `CommandTimeout = 0`. You shall never ever do that, except to diagnose whether your query takes too long.

Instead, you shall consider setting the timeout property to what's acceptable from your software performance requirements. Try to figure out how long it takes to execute, and set the **CommandTimeout** accordingly.

The default value is 30 seconds. Perhaps your query requires 45 seconds or more to execute. Find what works, which will allow you to set what is the normal time of execution. Then, when it takes longer, this will mean that there is something wrong which won't necessarily be your code.

Furthermore, try to figure out whether your query could use more indexes or the like, analyze its execution plan through [**SSAS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Analysis_Services), this shall point out what requires the most time out of your query.